# Did I analyze the structure of this sentence correctly?

Tags: grammar

For more context, see the full text:
https://www.docdroid.net/qteAJpo/img-20170628-0002-new.pdf.html

It is from line 13-14:
頭の中に具体的に理想の自分がイメージできたら、立っている位置を変えて、今の、つまりイメージの中では過去の自分と向き合うのです。

"When the self of concrete ideals comes up in the mind and you switch the position you are standing on, in other words in the inside of the image of now, you are face to face with your past self."

The placement of つまり for example confused me because at least from my foreign perspective its like its just thrown into the clause it belongs to xD 
Also, I feel unsure about my understanding of the clause ranging from 今の to 中では and its integration into the surrounding. I didn't really know what to make of the particle で in this particular context, and I think my rather bumpy translation reflects this, because the image (pun intended) that comes to mind when reading this part seems overly complicated to me...^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

つまり is summing up what has just been said.  It seems to me like you've got it perfectly right.  I'd translate the sentence a bit differently, but I think you've done a decent job.  Here's how I'd approach it.

> If in your mind you can concretely imagine your ideal self, swap the place where you are standing, **in other words** in this imagining the you who you are now is facing the you who you were in the past.

If I wanted this to sound a bit more fluid in English then I might take greater liberties with the translation and render it as

> Once you've managed to imagine your ideal self, swap places.  In other words, you imagine that you are now your future self facing your current self.

I think part of what you might be struggling with is are the relative clauses 今の and 過去の.  You could think of "の” as being "of", but I think it's much better in this context to think of it as a particular form of ”だ” used to modify a following noun.

Comment: how can you tell that 立っている位置を変えて is request form 立っている位置を変えて(ください) and not a compound sentence?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I can't necessarily except for context.  Also, I think it makes the English a bit more natural.  But overall, the piece seems to be advice from this author about how s/he achieved their success and in that context I think it's a justifiable reading, particularly since the essay ends with a suggestion of this is a method to achieve one's (the reader's) success.

Comment: I see, yeah I think it makes sense!!